# Laravel hasManyThrough with multiple key fields

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make what I think is a Laravel hasManyThrough relation with multiple key fields. My database looks like:

- **Employees**

  - id
  - team_id > references Teams
  - name
- **Teams**

  - id
  - teamleader1_user_id > references Employees
  - teamleader2_user_id > references Employees
  - teamleader3_user_id > references Employees

I'm aware the database setup is less than ideal but as it is an external application database I'm unable to change anything.

In my model for Employee I would like to create a relationship that makes it possible to extract all employees belonging to an employee via one of the teamleader fields in Teams. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it as ManyToMany relationship, bundled with three OneToMany.

```
class Team extends Model{
public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');
}

public function teamleader1()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Employee','teamleader1_user_id');
}

public function teamleader2()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Employee','teamleader2_user_id');
}

public function teamleader3()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Employee','teamleader3_user_id');
}
}

class Employee extends Model {
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team');
    }
}
```

You may have an intermediate table called employee_team with that "name" attribute on it. For more info you can check [Many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationships on Laravel Docs.

Comment: OK, but how would I fetch all employees belonging to another employee through all of the teamleader relations at once, like Employee->employees()?